# Changes to /etc/hosts are not recognized by shell commands until logging out and logging back in

Tags: bash, shell

I noticed this behavior on my server today and I'd like to understand more about what's happening.

When issuing the `w` command while ssh'ed into my RHEL 6 server I was attempting to have the FROM field print the hostname rather than the IP of the SSH client. Note that I use 8.8.8.8 for DNS and that resolution of google.com works fine with `ping`, for example.

So I edited /etc/hosts on the SSH server to include an entry for the client. Pinging the client by hostname now works fine, but `w` still displays the IP address in the FROM field.

Simply logging out and logging back in and issuing `w` again allowed the FROM field to list the SSH client by the hostname I configured in /etc/hosts.

My question is, why was the logout/login necessary? What changed or got updated upon logging back in?

I'm using bash-4.1.2-33.el6_7.1, the latest available in RHEL 6 base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`w` reads `/var/run/utmp` to find out who is logged in and where they logged in from.  `utmp` records are updated when a user logs in or logs out.

If there was no DNS or `/etc/hosts` entry for the IP *at the time the user logged in* then the hostname field in `utmp` is left empty by the login process (sshd in this case).

When you logged out and logged in again after adding the `/etc/hosts` entry, `sshd` performed a lookup on the IP and this time found a hostname, so was able to add the correct data to the hostname field in `utmp`.

see `man 5 utmp` for details on the file format of `/var/run/utmp`